# Could not resolve host - DNS configuration

Tags: php, curl, dns

By curl in PHP access remote site. It works well for months. Now give Error 6: "Could not resolve host".

It works locally, but not on the online site. Is it a problem in the dns hosting?
What can perform tests to confirm? Is there any way to fix it?

Locally ping host loses all packages, but curl running.
I check dns doing the hosting control panel get this error (where www.host.com is replaced by the remote site):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7 <<>> www.host.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 12692
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Comment: Re-run `dig` with the `+trace` option and post the output here, run it on your local computer too, then compare the results to see where the SERVFAIL response is coming from.

Comment: Locally I have windows, and does not recognize "dig + trace host" ... any alternatives?

Comment: Install windows dig in, and it works well. Get to host locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like whatever server is configured on the host to resolve DNS queries isn't working, if it is a *NIX system check the configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf` and see what servers are configured.  You can then use dig to perform your query directly against those servers and see if it resolves correctly.  Maybe there is an old bad entry in there for a dead server?  A response of SERVFAIL sounds like there is a problem in whichever DNS resolver the host is trying to use.

The syntax to query directly against a particular host is :

```
dig www.google.com @192.168.1.1

dig <domain name> @<DNS resolver IP>
```

Comment: DNS resolver IP is the last host that is accessed in the local trace? or ip  server hosting the site?

Comment: Neither, DNS resolver is the DNS server that translates the domain name into an IP address, it will not appear on a trace as it has nothing to do with the actual TCP/IP connection.  If you try `dig -t ns www.google.com` you will see a list of name servers for google.com for example.  These are the authorative servers responsible for the google.com domain. When you use a domain name you must first convert it to the target IP, so you speak to a DNS server which is like an internet phone book, just as you would look up a phone number, you need to look up an IP address.

Comment: This page may explain it more clearly : http://computer.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm

Comment: So if my dns is x, I ping X to get your ip I. And I can dig www.google.com @I know what happens? If this is correct, it gave me: 3 dns well, one refused. With these data the hosting will try to change the settings. Thank you